# How to overrride mediaViewDisplaySize for a custom media item in JSQMessagesViewController?

Tags: ios, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to customize the size of a custom media item in JSQMessagesViewController. I am adding a label to a UIView and trying to set the size by setting the frame size of my container view.

```
UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) ]
containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 315.0f, 100.0f);
UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
label.text = @"vendor name";
[containerView addSubview:label];
```

Setting frame size works for image view but now UIView. Even then, there is a white space for unfilled content in case of image view.
Also, I can resize the placeholder for all the views by `mediaViewDisplaySize` but then I cannot customize each subclass differently.

How do I selectively set the size for placeholderview depending on the subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `mediaItem` subclass, you'll need to override `mediaViewDisplaySize`. If you need different sizes for each type of `mediaItem`, then subclassing each will be easiest.